# C++ MySql Connector /MDd source build

Tags: c++, mysql, cmake

I need a version of the mysqlcppconn.dll using Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd).  This is because the default vesion I downloaded resulted in getInt() returning bad data.

I've been strugging with CMake and finally got it to generate a project.  This was using the GUI with "source code" and "where to build the binaries" as

```
C:/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.1/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.1/cppconn
C:/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.1/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.1/project
```

I kept getting "Unkown Command" errors so I had to add these in.

```
INCLUDE(CheckIncludeFiles) 
INCLUDE(CheckTypeSize) 
INCLUDE(CheckFunctionExists)
```

Unfortunately the project was completely empty of source code!  There were three projects

```
ALL_BUILD
INSTALL
ZERO_CHECK
```

I'm running Server 2008 and VS 2010.

Help!  I feel like I'm a one legged man in a kicking contest!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Was a coding issue, not a DLL issue.  Thanks